# Spotify authorization code - get token [ console application ]

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm writing a console application to create a playlist on Spotify according to a list of song. I'm using Spotipy and I'm trying with `util.prompt_for_user_token()`, the problem is that after I grant access I have to manually paste the redirect link into the console.

```
User authentication requires interaction with your
    web browser. Once you enter your credentials and
    give authorization, you will be redirected to
    a url.  Paste that url you were directed to to
    complete the authorization.
```

Is there a way to automate this process? The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133520/what-do-i-do-with-a-spotify-api-authentication-redirect-uri-in-django/42443878#42443878) didn't help me

Comment: I ran into the same exact issue while running [sconsify](http://www.sconsify.org/), I don't think there is an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt_for_user_token` function is a shorthand for some functionality provided by Spotipy. Here's the code of the function itself.

https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/spotipy/util.py

```
[ -- snip -- ]

def prompt_for_user_token(username, scope=None, client_id = None,
    client_secret = None, redirect_uri = None, cache_path = None):
''' prompts the user to login if necessary and returns
    the user token suitable for use with the spotipy.Spotify 
    constructor
    Parameters:
     - username - the Spotify username
     - scope - the desired scope of the request
     - client_id - the client id of your app
     - client_secret - the client secret of your app
     - redirect_uri - the redirect URI of your app
     - cache_path - path to location to save tokens
'''

[ -- snip -- ]

cache_path = cache_path or ".cache-" + username
sp_oauth = oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, 
    scope=scope, cache_path=cache_path)

[ -- snip -- ]

token_info = sp_oauth.get_cached_token()

if not token_info:
    print('''
        User authentication requires interaction with your
        web browser. Once you enter your credentials and
        give authorization, you will be redirected to
        a url.  Paste that url you were directed to to
        complete the authorization.
    ''')
    auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
    try:
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open(auth_url)
        print("Opened %s in your browser" % auth_url)
    except:
        print("Please navigate here: %s" % auth_url)

[ -- snip -- ]
```

You can replicate the code and use `auth_url` (for example) with `popen` module and `chrome.exe`, passing `auth_url` as an argument.

TIP: Under windows `cmd.exe /c start http://your.website/address` will forward the address to your current default browser. (as opposed to hardcoding `firefox.exe` or `chrome.exe`)

Comment: From what you're saying I suppose there's no way to retrieve the "redirected url" with `webbrowser`, so I need to find a way to do it manually, is that right?

Comment: Just write your own `prompt_for_user_token` function based on the one I quoted. Instead of `webbrowser.open(auth_url)` use `return auth_url`, and you have a function that returns you your URL. There is also another issue here, you could try installing `webbrowser` python module with `pip` and it won't default to `print("Please navigate here: %s" % auth_url)`.

Comment: Currently `webbrowser.open(auth_url)` doesn't work apparently, since code jumps to `except:` code there

Comment: `webbrowser.open(auth_url)` is working for me, the problem is that after I log into Spotify I'm redirected to some url that I need to paste in the console, I still haven't figured how to automatically get that url

Comment: I can only point you further. Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/929686/get-url-of-current-active-tab-from-firefox-via-command-line